# Android application goes in background after calling finish in an activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application with two `Activity`s.

The first `Activity` starts the second `Activity` on a `Button` click. In the second `Activity`, after I call `finish()`, also on a `Button` click, I expect that the application will return to the first `Activity`.

What happen is that the application gets minimized (goes in background). The device on which I am developing is a Sony Xperia Z2 with Android 4.4.2. 
Is this an Android issue or is it something wrong that I am doing in code?

**The manifest file:**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.test.SecondActivity">
</application>
```

**First activity onClick:**

```
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

**Second activity onClick:**

```
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: please post your activity finish code.

Comment: and also the manifest

Comment: and also check `Don't Kepp activities` that be unselected on Developer option -> APPs section

Comment: how you start second activity in your code? please post that too

Comment: did you override onStop or onPause method in first activity? did you check my first comment?

Comment: I have posted the code from the button click listeners.

Comment: @shayan pourvatan I am checking it right now.

Comment: "Don't Kepp activities" does not change the behavior of the application. It is still minimized.

Comment: @RaduStejerean make sure you don't have `finish();` anywhere in your first `Activity`. If there is, share the snippet.

Comment: Post your logcat - it could be your app is silently crashing.

Comment: @Sufian This is all the code from the onCreate methods. I do not call finish anywhere in the Activities.

Comment: @RaduStejerean did you test on Emulator? what happened on that? or other mobile device

Comment: @shayan pourvatan on the emulator I have tried with lower android versions and it is not reproducible.

Comment: @Squonk the app is not crashing. It simply goes in background. Like pressing the home button.

Comment: @RaduStejerean sharing the `LogCat` isn't really a bad idea either. It might help us.

Comment: @RaduStejerean : How do you know it's not crashing? Have you looked at logcat? If an app crashes silently it just disappears and will still show in Recent apps as if you had pressed home.

Comment: @Squonk: The problem is that I work in a company and I don't have permissions to post the logcat content. I assure you that there aren't any errors in the logcat.

Comment: @RaduStejerean : In that case you're unlikely to find an answer. All I'll say is what you're experiencing is NOT standard Android behaviour. You haven't posted enough code for anybody to be able to answer your question. The AndroidManifest doesn't tell us anything and the only other code you've posted is two snippets of anonymous `OnClickListener` classes.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that it is not a Android issue.

Secondly, please make sure you have not finished your first `Activity` when you are moving from First to Second.

If you are doing this in first class:

```
Intent in=new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(in);
this.finish();
```

then remove `this.finish();` because it finishes up your first `Activity` and when you are coming back from second then first `Activity` is not present in the stack. So how it would be called.

Comment: why you said that "it is not a Android issue."? so what is this issue ?

Comment: My friend its a coding issue.

Comment: OK Ronak but this is android coding issue, not java or c++.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan eh? Why are you mentioning C++ here? There's no C++ tag on this question or mention of it.

Comment: @Sufian I'm want to tell Ronak that this is Android issue, she/he said that "its a coding issue" and "it is not a Android issue", I told that it's android issue not any other programming code, (like java or ... )

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Android only does what you ask it to. I'd suspect a coding mistake, some settings issue, or maybe some mistake in testing.

Answer (score -1):

First.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class First extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
         b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    finish();
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Second.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Second extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
         b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    finish();
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: What @RaduStejerean doesn't realize is that he may have problem somewhere else in code. He can use your code to see if it helps though.